# How to create the column in pandas based on values of another column

Tags: pandas

I have created a new column, by adding values from one column, to the index of the column from which I have created this new column. However, my problem is the code works fine when I implement on sample column, but when I pass the already existing dataframe, it throws the error, "can only perform ops with scalar values". As per what I found is the code expects dist and that is why it is throwing error.

I tried converting the dataframe to dictionary or to a list, but no luck.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Sam', 'Andrea', 'Alex', 'Robin', 'Kia',    'Sia'], 'Age':[14,25,55,8,21,43], 'd_id_max':[2,1,1,2,0,0]})`

df['Expected_new_col'] = df.loc[df.index + df['d_id_max'].to_list, 'Age'].to_numpy()

print(df)
```

> error: can only perform ops with scalar values.

This is the dataframe I want to implement this code:

```
      Weight   Name     Age     1     2   abs_max d_id_max
  0     45     Sam      14     11.0  41.0   41.0    2
  1     88     Andrea   25     30.0 -17.0   30.0    1
  2     56     Alex     55    -47.0 -34.0   47.0    1
  3     15     Robin    8      13.0  35.0   35.0    2
  4     71     Kia      21     22.0  24.0   24.0    2
  5     44     Sia      43     2.0   22.0   22.0    2
  6     54     Ryan     45     20.0  0.0    20.0    1
```

Comment: Explain what you want to do in a logical matter, instead of "why is my code not working". It's a good idea to also include your expected output based on the dataframe you provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing your new column like this will not return an error:

```
df.loc[df.index + df['d_id_max'], 'Age'].to_numpy()
```

EDIT:
You should first format `d_id_max` as `int` (or `float`):

```
df['d_id_max'] = df['d_id_max'].astype(int)
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with something that should work, @Saurabh

Comment: @Saurabh I just tried it with the code you posted above, and it worked. Are you trying it out on different code?

Comment: Yeah, that's my problem.  If you go through my 1st question post, I mentioned that my code does not work the same way when I am passing   another existing dataframe.

Comment: If you want us to help you, please post an example in which the error reproduces - else there's not much we can do

Comment: Can you put something we can copy and paste rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Either way, my first thought is that perhaps `d_id_max` is formatted as a string. Can you post the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Happy to help :) Remember that you can upvote/accept an answer if you found it useful

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple, I was getting the error because the data type of the column d_id_max was object type, which should be either float or integer, so i change the data type and it worked fine.